# Preprocessor Macro and Boolean in IOS 8 not correctly evaluated

Tags: ios, macros, ios8

Combining pre-processor macro and a boolean is incorrectly evaluated in IOS8

I am running this on an IPHONE 4 with IOS 8. The code functions correctly on IOS 7

Do we have to change code to stop using these macros ?

```
#define isiPhone4  ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)?FALSE:TRUE

    BOOL myBool = YES;
    if (myBool || isiPhone4) {
        NSLog(@"TRUE");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"FALSE");
    }

    if (myBool) {
        NSLog(@"TRUE");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"FALSE");
    }

    if (isiPhone4) {
        NSLog(@"TRUE");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"FALSE");
    }
```

output
FALSE
TRUE
TRUE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your macro: because you did not enclose it in parentheses, prefixing it with a logical expression can change its meaning.

This is a very common problem - precisely the reason why one should avoid macros in situations that do not strictly require them (that is, in most situations). When your macro is expanded in place, Objective-C compiler sees this condition:

```
if (myBool || ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)?FALSE:TRUE) {
    ...
}
```

It gets parsed as follows:

- Condition: `myBool || ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)`
- On true: `FALSE`
- On false: `TRUE`

Note how `myBoo ||` became part of the condition. This is because of C precedence rules. Remember, by the time the compiler parses the expression, it has no idea that one part of the expression came from a macro, while the other part was in the code before the macro expansion.

Here is how you can fix it:

```
#define isiPhone4  (([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)?FALSE:TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you for the speedy answer. You are quite correct , Why is this only an issue on IOS 8 ?

Comment: @RyanHeitner It is os-agnostic. I tried it on iOS 7.1 and got the same output.

Comment: It was another issue in my IOS 7 - This is only on IOS8 Thanks